# using moq to return a real object from a property

Tags: c#, mvvm, moq

OK - So, I have been trying to search for this but I probably have my understanding (and hence wording) of the question wrong so I will do my best to explain and hopefully someone can make sense of what I need to do and point me in the right direction - here goes.

I have a view model, the view model takes and adapter which I mock - no problem there, but the asserts I want to write are going to check that setting certain properties of the view model updated certain properties of an object that is itself a property of the adapter. I understand how to use setup to say anytime a method is called return "X" but this isn't a method, it's a property and I am stumped - seems like it outta be simple.

Here is some code from the view model that gives you an idea of what I am doing.

```
public bool OnlyUseFedEx
{
  get { return vendorQualitativeMetricsAdapter.VendorQualitativeMetric.OnlyUseFedEx; }
  set { vendorQualitativeMetricsAdapter.VendorQualitativeMetric.OnlyUseFedEx = value; }
}
```

Here is what I started with the test method

```
    [TestMethod]
public void VQM_ShippingViewModel_Can_Update_Adapters_vendorManagementProxy()
{
  var vendorManagementProxy = new VendorManagementProxy();
  var vqmAdapter = new Mock<IVendorQualitativeMetricsAdapter>();
  //This is where I would like to say - always return that vendorManagementProxy object I created. 
  vqmAdapter.Setup(a => a.VendorQualitativeMetric ???
  ShippingViewModel shippingViewModel;
}
```

OK - Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use `Returns` on the `Setup` call? Maybe I misunderstood the question though...

```
vqmAdapter.Setup(a => a.VenderQualitativeMetric).Returns(venderManagementProxy)
```

[this](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) is a good place to start looking for MoQ tips and tricks :-)

Comment: Yeah - these are both correct... I just had an error in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SetupGet`:

```
vqmAdapter.SetupGet(a => a.VendorQualitativeMetric).Returns(vendorManagementProxy);
```

---

Update: I've just learnt that you can also use `Setup` too - see [Setup() vs SetupGet()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767640/moq-setup-vs-setupget) - according to that answer, which you use "is probably ... personal preference"